# Ember is printing Hello World! twice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, coffeescript

I'm just trying to get a basic ember app up and running on a rails back-end. In application.js I have the following:

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

Ew = Ember.Application.create();
```

router.coffee:

```
Ew.Router.map ->
  @.resource('hi')
```

index.hbs:

```
<p>{{#linkTo hi}}say hello{{/linkTo}}</p>
```

hi.hbs:

```
<h1>Hello!</h1>
```

When I load the page everything is working as it should. There's a link at the top that says `say hello`.

When i click the link the url at `/#/hi` renders, as it should. But when I click the back button to go back to the index template and then the forward button to go to the hi template, "Hello World!" shows up twice.

Anyone ever seen this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't remove

```
//= require turbolinks
```

from application.js. I suppose that interferes with the pushState functionality in Ember.